# Discord.js counting system

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

so I was trying to make my own version of a counting system for my server like how other bots such as countr do it, so I made the following:

```js
if (message.channel.id === "794733520458612736") {
    const numdb = db.get("numdb");
    if (message.content === numdb) {
        db.add("numdb", 1);
        message.react("✅");
    } else if (typeof message.content === "number") {
        db.set("numdb", 1);
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} ruined it at **${numdb}**! The next number is **1**.`);
        message.react("❌");
    };
};
```

Yet, when I try it, it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Wait, would I have to add `&& message.content !== numdb` to the else if? EDIT: Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: `message.content` will always be a string. Is `numdb` a number? Triple equals check the value and type too. Would this work with double equals (`message.content  == numdb`) instead?

Comment: Hmm, let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I solved it as shown below:

```js
if (message.channel.id === "794733520458612736") {
    const numdb = db.get("numdb");
    if (message.content == `${numdb}`) {
        db.add("numdb", 1);
        message.react("✅");
    } else if (!isNaN(message.content) && message.content != `${numdb}`) {
        db.set("numdb", 1);
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} ruined it at **${numdb-1}**! The next number is **1**.`);
        message.react("❌");
    };
};
```

I figured out that the reason was because `===` checks both value and type (credit to Zsolt) and the old method I used to check if it was a number didn't work, so I switched it to `isNaN`.